# Comment « accuser » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « confirmer la bonne réception » ?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « blâmer, déférer à la justice quelqu’un comme coupable d’un délit, d’un crime. » (les acceptions plus coutumières) avec #10 sur [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accuser#Verbe)

> 10. [Marquer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marquer), [donner](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/donner) [avis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avis) qu’on l’a [reçu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/re%C3%A7u).
>
>     - ***Accuser** réception d’une lettre, d’un paquet, etc.,*
>     - ***Accusez**-moi réception de ma lettre,*

et [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/accuser/592/locution?q=accuser#177481)?

> **Accuser réception de quelque chose** [=] notifier à l'expéditeur la réception de quelque chose.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a quelques notes étymologiques (pas très lisibles) dans le [Trésor de la langue française](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accuser) (voir à la fin de ACCUSER²). Le sens original d'accuser n'est pas seulement lier à la justice : il s'applique dès que l'on dit publiquement que quelqu'un est coupable, même sans processus judiciaire. Apparemment ce sens a évolué dèjà en latin tardif ou au moins en latin médiéval pour s'élargir à toute révélation publique, puis l'aspect de culpabilité a disparu d'un certain nombre de sens. L'évolution est donc : révéler que quelqu'un est coupable → révéler quelque chose.

Le mot ne s'est pas généralisé dans le sens de « révéler, laisser apparaître », mais il a pris ce sens dans plusieurs contextes spécialisés (voir TLFI) dans des contextes tels que « accuser réception » (révéler qu'on a reçu), « accuser le coup » (laisser apparaître les conséquences d'une difficulté), « accuser une caractéristique » (laisser voir une caractéristique)...

Answer (score -1):

Il ne semble pas falloir chercher plus loin pour l'essentiel que dans l'étymologie du verve « accuser » telle que donnée par le 
[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accuser) ; elle est reproduite ci-dessous.

> Étymol. ET HIST.
>   **I. Objet animé**. 1. Xe s. terme jur. « mettre en cause, porter accusation contre qqn aux fins de condamnation en justice » (sans indication de motif) (*Passion*, éd. d'Arco Silvio Avalle, 203 : Fortment lo vant il **acusand**, La soa mort mult demandant; et *ibid*. 215 : Judeu l'**acusent**, el se tais); 2. *id*. avec indication de motif, 1155 (WACE, *Brut*, partie arthurienne, éd. Arnold et Pelan 2148 : Et an semonant te comande Que tu soies an mi aost A Rome a lui, que qu'il te cost, Aparelliez de fere droit De ce que tu li as toloit Si feras satisfaction De ce que nos t'**acuseron**).
>
> **II. Objet inanimé**.
>   1. *ca* 1152 terme jur. « dénoncer, incriminer (un fait répréhensible) pour exciter la réprobation » (*Li dialoge Gregoire lo Pape*, éd. W. Fœrster, 15, 3 ds T.-L. : n'**acusat** pas lo visce del pere de l'abie); 1173 « révéler (le corps d'un délit) » id. (*Aiol et Mirabel*, éd. W. Fœrster, 9 735 ds T.-L. : ilor **fu acussés** Uns mout tresgrans tressors qu'il quidoient enbler);
>    2. ca 1205 « signaler (qqc.) dans un esprit hostile » (*Guillaume de Palerne*, éd. H. Michelant, 1062 : tot ce qui me plaist refusent Et ce que celer voel **acusent**).
>   Empr. au lat. jur. *accusare* au sens I 1 dep. PLAUTE, *Asinaria*, 491 ds TLL, 350, 21 (*cf. Vulg. Marc*., XV, 3 : et accusabant eum summi sacerdotes), au sens I 2 dep. CICÉRON, *Verr*., 2, 43, *ibid*., 351, 10; ces 2 emplois très attestés en lat. médiév. jur. (ds *Mittellat. W. s.v.*); au sens II 1 dep. PLAUTE, *Epidicus*, 549 ds *TLL*, 353, 36; cf. SÉNÈQUE, *Controversiae*, 2, 6, 5, *ibid*., 353, 71 : vitia patris; pas d'équivalent ds *Mittellat. W. s.v*.; II 2 semble un élargissement de sens de II 1; cf. aussi au sens de « signaler » [part. passé] *Leges Wisigoth*., 4, 5, 6 ds *Mittellat. W. s.v. accusatus*, adj. : accusatum sibi negotium destitit iudicare iudex.  Hyp. *EWFS2* qui voit en II 2 [XIIe] un développement pop. à partir du lat., en I, II 1 [XIIIe s.] une réfection de II 2 d'apr. le lat., fait appel à une distinction inutile : I très anciennement attesté, est directement empr. au lat. et non dû à une réfection d'apr. le lat., d'un 1er sens « signaler »; de même II 1; II 2 est une ext. de II 1.

C'est dans la partie « êtres inanimés » au « II » de cette étymologie que l'on trouve qu'à partir de 1205 le sens de « signaler quelque chose dans un esprit  hostile » prend forme ; il ne faut pas oublier que mettre à l'obligation de donner une preuve de la réception d'une pièce implique une mise en cause *non amicale* selon laquelle, l'honnêteté de la personne est de prime abord doutée, ce qui est insultant sans la justification que la loi apporte au nom du bon déroulement des procédures légales, c'est à dire le besoin de fournir une base meilleure pour les divers rapports entre des personnes redevables devant la loi. De cela la notion d'hostilité devient explicable. Il me semble que le « glissement » n'est pas si important et que le concept découle presque directement de ce sens premier.

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'hostilité dans « accuser réception ». Le glissement est justement que l'aspect d'hostilité ou de culpabilité a disparu.

Comment: @Gilles C'est ce que je comprends, mais je suspecte que c'est le tour légal que le concept a pris qui a estompé cet aspect ; cela me semble clair dans ce que j'écris.